# InvalidArgumentException route notdefined

Tags: laravel

I have error like (1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Route [home] not defined. whenever i used the store function but i'm pretty sure that i use the redirect method  right what could be the possible error, all i wanted was to redirect to home once the store method is done.

web.php

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('main');
}); 

Route::get('/create', 'BuildingController@createBuilding');
Route::post('/store', 'BuildingController@store');
Route::post('home', 'BuildingController@getAllBuilding');
```

Building.php

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Building extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
         'id',
         'building_name', 
         'building_information',
         'building_image'
    ];
}
```

BuildingController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Building;
use Image;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\Building\BuildingRepository;

class BuildingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    private $building;

    public function __construct(BuildingRepository $building)
    {
        $this->building = $building;
    }

    public function createBuilding()
    {
       return view('building.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $this->validate($request, array(
           'building_name'=>'required',
           'building_information'=>'required',
           'building_image' => 'required'
       ));

            $image = $request->file('building_image');
            $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('images/' .$filename);
            Image::make($image)->resize(800,400)->save($location);

             $buildings = array('building_name' => $request->building_name,
                            'building_information' => $request->building_information,
                            'building_image' => $filename);

        $this->building->create($buildings);

        return redirect()->route('home');

    }

    public function getAllBuilding()
    {
        $buildings =  $this->building->getAll();
        return view('building.home')->with('buildings', $buildings);
    }

    public function getSpecificRecord()
    {
        $buildings = $this->building->getById(1);
        return view('building.show')->with('buildings', $buildings);
    }
}
```

EloquentBuilding.php

```
 <?php


namespace App\Repositories\Building;

use \App\Building;

class EloquentBuilding implements BuildingRepository
{   
    private $model;

    public function __construct(Building $model)
    {   
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->model->all();
    }

    public function create(array $attributes)
    {
        return $this->model->create($attributes);
    }

    public function update($id, array $attributes)
    {

    }

    public function delete($id)
    {

    }          
}
```

BuildingRepository.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Repositories\Building;


interface BuildingRepository
{
    public function getById($id);

    public function getAll();

    public function create(array $attributes); 

    public function update($id, array $attributes);

    public function delete($id);            
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `route()`, you need to [name the route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes). Also, make it `get`:

```
Route::get('home', 'BuildingController@getAllBuilding')->name('home');
```

Or:

```
Route::get('home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'BuildingController@getAllBuilding']);
```

Comment: it works but i found a new error (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: @JoselParayno have you changed it to `get`?

Comment: it's alright now i used the Route::get('home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'BuildingController@getAllBuilding']);

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use route with `post`, replace it with `get` and also add/specify name attribute to call route using name.

```
Route::get('home', 'BuildingController@getAllBuilding')->name('home');
```

OR

```
Route::get('home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'BuildingController@getAllBuilding']);
```

Above both are comes with same output...

Comment: by default the form uses POST right? how did it became GET?

Comment: @JoselParayno just curious why have you chosen this answer which is exactly like mine and you told it works for you before even Narendra created his answer?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin is it ok now?